# Database first with Entity Framework Core ,oracle 11g (v11.2 ) and Scaffold-DbContext

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create Entity classes from already created oracle database by using Scaffold-DbContext.
I used the following command to generate the same but I am getting just DbContext with no entity classes.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=data-source;User ID=user-id;Password=****" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models
```

I am unable to find a good source for EntityFramework core used with oracle.
Can anyone please point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error you getting!!

Comment: I am not getting any error. I am unable to generate Entity classes

Comment: All your tables need a primary key, if you use EF Core 2.x

Comment: All my table have primary key but it is not being generated by Scaffold-DbContext tool

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following. Change the variable per your requirements.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=1.1.1.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MYdb)));Persist Security Info=True;User Id=USER;Password=mypass;" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models
```

Update:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST= (ADDRESS=(COMMUNITY=tcpcom.world)(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST={Host})(PORT={Port})))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID={SID}))); User ID={UserId};Password={Password}" {Provider} -o Models
```

Comment: Let me try this out

Comment: need to ensure there is a no $ in the password.

Comment: No change in the result... I am able to generate DbContext class but unable to generate the entity classes from database

Comment: I cannot change password of the oracle db.. as I am not maintaining it

Comment: it needed to be escaped by placing a backtick ` in front of the $

Comment: try escaping the $ with a back tick

Comment: Same result no change..
The table are inside a other users in oracle database..